# Why does this bit of code work in Java 7 and not Java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm currently using IDE Eclipse Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) and version java Version 8 Update 131.
In this code, the IDE gives an error - "Type mismatch: can not convert from byte to Integer":

```
Integer i = (byte) 10;
```

But this code is correctly executed in IDE Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2 and java Version 7. What essentially changed in the widening conversion mechanism in the 8th version of java, because I do not think it is related to the IDE version?

Comment: So your question can be summarized as "Why does this bit of code work in Java 7 and not Java 8?".

Comment: Yes, i don't understand, why this code works fine in java 7

Comment: I Tried this in java 7 and 8 both gave me the same error. are you sure this worked in java 7

Comment: Yes, i absolutely sure! Maybe this related for Eclipse version?

Comment: @janith1024 Did you use `javac`? I can confirm, that this works in Eclipse Indigo SR2 (ECJ). So, that seems to be a bug in ECJ.

Comment: Looks like an implicit conversion. Some shortcut of: "int prim = (byte) 10; Integer i = prim;"

Comment: I checked this bit of code in Intellij idea with different JDKs(7 & 8) hope issue in Eclipse version

Comment: *I do not think it is related to the IDE version*. And why is that?

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely not an issue with JDK, because on command line using the `javac` compiler, the code throws the same compiler error with both JDK 7 and JDK 8 -

```
error: incompatible types
Integer i = (byte) 10;
            ^
```

In fact , I have Eclipse Mars Release 4.5.0 and it gives me the same compilation error with JDK 7 and 8. I don't have the newer versions so haven't tested on those, but if it is not throwing compilation error on any of the releases with JDK 7 then it must be a bug with the eclipse compiler of that JDK version.

Answer (score 7):

Your assignment would only work, if two conversions were made at once

1. Widening from `byte` to `int`
2. Boxing from `int` to `Integer`

Apparently, older Eclipse versions allowed this, which has been changed, whereas `javac` never allowed this (I tested Java 6 to Java 9).

To find out, what is the correct behavior, we have do refer to [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> #### 5.2. Assignment Contexts
>
> Assignment contexts allow the value of an expression to be assigned (§15.26) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Note that the combination we would need for the code is not within the list. We can derive from that list, that the following should work:

```
Number i = (byte) 10;
```

which is a boxing conversion from `byte` to `Byte`, followed by a widening reference conversion to `Number`.

or

```
Byte b = 42;
int i = b;
```

which is an unboxing conversion from `Byte` to `byte`, followed by a widening primitive conversion from `byte` to `int`.

Since `(byte) 10` is a compile-time constant, we also have to consider

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
>   - `Short` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `short`.
>   - `Character` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `char`.

from the same section.

This allows some interesting combinations like

```
Character c = (byte)10;
```

or

```
Byte b = 'x';
```

but none with a variable type of `Integer`

---

As said, the conversion from `byte` to `Integer` is not within the list, so the fact that older Eclipse versions allowed it, can be considered a bug that has been fixed in the newer version.

Comment: Apparently, you are wright, that the older version of Eclipse allowed this conversion "byte to Integer", but i not found any references for this bug(or this enhancement) and this fact is interesting.

Comment: Not every fix has an explicit bug report, sometimes, it’s part of a rewrite of a particular algorithm that will fix more than one issue.

Comment: Ok, i thing this topic should be closed, because the changing code to `Integer i = Integer.valueOf((byte) 10)`, for example, is the best way.

Comment: @Vitaly Vlasov: you question was *why*, not how to change the code. If you want to know, how to fix that problem in the code, well, just remove the obsolete `(byte)` cast, `Integer i = 10;` and you’re done. If you have an existing variable `b` of type `byte`, you can simply write `Integer i = +b;`, considering that unary `+` is a no-op. But that was not your question. So I don’t see, why this question should be closed. You may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer instead…

Comment: First, up-vote. I think the code also can't be compiled in eclipse. It is an error rather than a warning. So I want to ask OP how do you make your code compile at compile-time in eclipse via `javac`? Maybe it doesn't occurs at all. or maybe the OP disabled the eclipse validation mechanism during writing code.

Answer (score 6):

Accepting the program was [bug 362279](https://bugs.eclipse.org/362279) in ecj, which was fixed in 2011.

PS: why bother investigating bugs in ancient versions? You're missing 1419 bug fixes only in JDT/Core.