# Why final byte variable cannot be converted to Integer during auto-boxing?

Tags: java, type-conversion, autoboxing

There is no error when I try to autobox `i2` to `Byte`,but when I do vise-versa(`b1` to `Integer`),then an error occurs.

```
        final byte b1 = 1;
        Integer i1 = b1; //error

        final int i2 = 1;
        Byte b2 = i2;// no error

        byte b3 = 1;
        int i3 = b3; // no error
```

Comment: I think the explanation is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105159/905488). I don't see how the variable being `final` makes any difference.

Comment: @MickMnemonic `final` matters in the 2nd example, because it makes `i2` a constant expression.

Comment: @Radiodef, but OP specifically asks about the first conversion where `final` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you read [JLS Sec 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), that I linked in my answer to your [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206288/why-during-autoboxing-final-long-to-byte-compilation-error-happens-but-final-in/46206395#46206395).

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening
>   reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>   primitive conversion.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte.
>   - ...

Taking your cases in reverse order:

```
    byte b3 = 1;
    int i3 = b3; // no error
```

Assigning a `byte` to an `int` is simply a widening conversion.

```
    final int i2 = 1;
    Byte b2 = i2;// no error
```

This is exactly the same as your previous question: you can assign a constant-valued `int` to a `Byte`, provided the value of that `int` fits into a `byte`.

```
    final byte b1 = 1;
    Integer i1 = b1; //error
```

You're trying to do a *widening* primitive conversion, followed by a *boxing conversion*. That's not one of the cases listed here, so it's an error.

You can fix this with an explicit widening cast:

```
    Integer i1 = (int) b1; //ok
```